# How to remove black edges on georeferenced images with GDAL

Tags: gdal

After an image has been georeferenced the transformation creates black edges, how could I set these to white instead of black using GDAL?

Would I have to somehow create a colour table and set nodata to white?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A nodata value is just that, no data. So the idea of having it white, black, or any other colour *within the dataset* doesn't make sense. Now, obviously when you load an image into a GIS, you have to represent nodata as *something*, and this is, in Quantum GIS at least, either whatever is underneath, or if there is nothing then the project's background colour. So there is a decoupling of what nodata *means*, how it is stored, and how it is represented.

If you're getting black regardless of the background colour of the GIS you're using, then the chances are GDAL hasn't set a nodata value at all, and it just defaults to black pixels. So you need to explicitly tell GDAL how you want nodata to be stored. With `gdalwarp` you use the `-dstnodata` command line switch to achieve this. You may find that nodata values in the source image aren't carried over in a warp operation, in which case you need to set it explicitly with `-srcnodata`. If you want to override an image's nodata vaue, you can do that with `gdal_translate -a_nodata ...`.

Answer (score 5):

Use GDAL's [nearblack](http://www.gdal.org/nearblack.html) utility.  It converts black, white or any specified color to black/white.

Answer (score 2):

Between gdal_translate and gdal2tiles.py, use gdalwarp with -dstnodata parameter. For example, if you want to turn these black edges to white (255 255 255):

```
gdal_translate <ORIGINAL_FILE.jpg> cache/transform/georef.tif -of GTiff -gcp 3798 138 26.355081965420457 59.34191837150522 -gcp 3448 4920 26.35345118233987 59.323597258855266 -gcp 8108 3875 26.387508872834236 59.327911749143276

gdalwarp -dstnodata "255 255 255" cache/transform/georef.tif cache/transform/warp.tif

gdal2tiles.py --profile mercator --s_srs 'GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]' --zoom 12-16 --title 'New tiles' --tile-format jpeg --webviewer all cache/transform/warp.tif <TILES_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY>
```